# Search for item within distance of user (geo-location) PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I have a mySQL table with item, latitude & longitude etc.
How would I go about searching for items within a certain number in KM's based on their current Geo-location?

Example:
A user selects a value from a drop down box '20KM'
How would I get all the items within a 20KM Distance based on their Geo-location?

Screenshot below of layout:

[image: Search button]

Comment: distance on air way or road? its important to finding location near your position.

Comment: @hosseinbarzegari   Distance via ROAD.

Comment: best solution is use google api , its help you and its path updated. altough i send an answer samplel code with source to you. ;)

Comment: Ok Thank you, will look shortly.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *,3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((19.286558 - latitude)*pi()/180/2),2)+COS(19.286558 * pi()/180)
*COS(latitude * pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((-99.612494 -longitude)* pi()/180/2),2)))
as distance FROM table  having distance < 10 ORDER BY distance;
```

This will give you records within 10 Km range. modify query for 20 meters in having clause.

Answer (score 0):

its best to use google sample code.

This link helps you:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

their PHP and SQL query helped really well.

**ADD:**

[this code](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php) may help also:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
      return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } else {
      return $miles;
  }
}
```

result:

```
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate strait distance between current location and all parks and filter only which matching distance criteria.

```
    /**
     * @param float $parkLatitude
     * @param float $parkLongitude
     * @param float $userLatitude
     * @param float $userLongitude
     * @param float $distance in km
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    function isParkInDistance($parkLatitude, $parkLongitude, $userLatitude, $userLongitude, $distance)
{
    $earthRadius = 6371; //km

    $dLat = deg2rad($userLatitude - $parkLatitude);
    $dLon = deg2rad($userLongitude - $parkLongitude);

    $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($parkLatitude)) * cos(deg2rad($userLatitude)) * sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);
    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));
    $d = $earthRadius * $c;

    return $d <= $distance;
}
```

Or you can use something like [this google service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) to calculate distance via roads